# Laravel 5.4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'common' of undefined

Tags: laravel

I'm stuck with this kind of error related to axios. This issue occurs when I use `npm run watch` and edit scss or vue files. After editing scss or vue files, the browser reloads and produce this error.

[image]

Found this [link](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1120) but no luck.
Tried also removing node_modules and do npm install.

Tried to dig into the browser's console and got

```
axios.defaults.headers
undefined
```

and when `axios.defaults.headers.common` it will display
the main error.

Comment: More information is required.

Comment: `axios.defaults.headers` is not defined.

Comment: @fubar, undefined on my end.

Comment: Yes, that's the cause of the error. So you're trying to access a property on an undefined object.

Comment: @fubar, yeah, haven't touch anything on the default app.js and bootstrap.js files. just doing the scss files and boom stuck when using `npm run watch`. No problem when using `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 0):

For the mean time, this will be cured by lowering the laravel-mix version to `0.*` in package.json and run `npm install`. Source link is [here](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1148#issuecomment-328718729)